# Connecting my Godox SK400 II with my Godox X1R-C Receiver

Tags: canon, flash, godox

Okay, so I finally want to delve into flash photography. But I'm having the hardest time connecting my Godox SK400 II with the X1R-C Receiver.

According to the product features, the SK400 II has a built-in, wireless 2.4G X system, which you can use to trigger the flash. So because of that, I didn't buy an extra trigger. I did buy the Godox X1R-C Receiver, which I've put on my camera and connected. Now, that connection between the receiver and the camera is working fine. But even though the flash and the receiver have been set to the same channel & group, the flash doesn't trigger when I press the shutter release button on the camera.

Can anyone tell me how to exactly sync these? Or am I missing an extra device, like an external trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a *receiver* on your camera, you need a *transmitter*.

The X1R-C receiver doesn't broadcast anything, it receives signals from a transmitter. It's made to use with non-Godox flashes compatible with Canon's flash system. The radio built into your SK 400 II is also a receiver (that will work with Godox transmitters for any brand: Canon, Sony, nikon, etc.). The radio receiver inside your SK400 II does the same thing the radio receiver built into the X1R-C does: it picks up signals from a Godox 2.4Ghz transmitter and relays the information to the flash connected to it.

Since you bought an X1R-C, I'm assuming you have a Canon EOS camera. If not, you need a transmitter that matches your camera manufacturer. S for Sony, N for Nikon, F for Fuji, and so on.

The direct transmitter equivalent to the X1R-C receiver is the X1T-C. Another option is the XPro-C. It gives up the hot shoe on top of the transmitter that still allows an on-camera flash in exchange for a larger screen and more buttons to make controlling several off camera groups faster and easier.

I use a Flashpoint R2 Pro Mark II to control all of my Flashpoint/Godox lights. Flashpoint is U.S. retailer Adorama's house brand for rebadged Godox products. In the UK PixaPro are rebadged Godox products. In Canada StrobePro are the same rebadged Godox products. There are others in Europe as well. The Flashpoint R2 Pro for Canon is identical to the Godox XPro-C. The Flashpoint R2 Pro Mark II for Canon is a newer Flashpoint only version that adds more buttons for direct access to groups A-E. It's also capable of 16 groups in manual control, but there aren't dedicated buttons for each of the 16 groups! (you have to scroll, the same way you do with all of the groups with the earlier version.) If I want an on-camera flash when using the transmitter, I mount the flash on a flash bracket that I'd use anyway to keep the flash above my camera even in portrait orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Gonna buy the XPro-C.